# iptables prevents connection via ssh after port change despite ACCEPT rule

Tags: ssh, centos, putty, sshd, timeout

I have two machines hooked up to a router, one Windows with PuTTY, and one CentOS 6.4 with sshd and with the default SELinux still enabled.  They can both ping each other successfully.

I installed the policycore-python package so I could use `semanage`, then followed [these directions](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH).

Step 4 looked like it's the new default, since it was already set up that way.

Step 5 worked and I assume the stuff about `~/.ssh/config` is for setting up your ssh client on another machine, so it doesn't apply (I can do something similar in PuTTY.)

Step 6 I figured the shortest and most applicable thing was the third option, so I ran:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2345 --syn -m limit --limit 1/m --limit-burst 3 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2345 --syn -j DROP
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

At this point, I can do `ssh -p 2345 localhost` and also `ssh -p 2345 192.168.1.4` on the CentOS box and log into itself fine, but I can no longer PuTTY into the CentOS box.  I put the right IP and port 2345 in the connection window, but upon attempting to connect, I get a black screen with a solid green cursor, which, after a few seconds, gives a GUI popup saying `Network error: Connection timed out`.

If I [stop the iptables service](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/comment/1144#comment-1144), I can log in using PuTTY the same way.  So it seems the problem is definitely with `iptables` and not `sshd` (nor `semanage`?).

What's wrong with my `iptables`?

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:2345 flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN limit: avg 1/min burst 3
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:2345 flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Is sshd really listening that port for the network interface? Try `lsof -i :2345`, also post your `iptables -L` rules.

Comment: @Braiam please see question update.

Comment: You sure configured putty to use port 2345 and sshd to listen same port when you cleared the iptables? Also verify that your iptables accepts connections to port 2345

Comment: @Braiam, yes, otherwise I wouldn't be able to log in via PuTTY after `service iptables stop`, right?  And I'm not sure how to verify what you said--I provided `iptables -L` output in my edit but I'm an `iptables` n00b.

Comment: @Braiam, Also `lsof` returns `command not found` or something like that.

Comment: `lsof` should be run as root and why just not using some gui or helper to make the `iptables` rules.

Comment: @Braiam, I don't have a GUI.  Do you have a recommended command-line tool?  I'd be interested, but as I said, I don't understand why an out-of-the-box iptable won't work with the commands from the official wiki.

Comment: It's because you are mixing old rules with new rules and the wiki assumes you are configuring iptables from scratch. Flush your tables, use the rules the wiki says and save your table. It should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `REJECT` rule has to come after the new rules.  Do this:

```
$ sudo service iptables stop
[sudo] password for kev:
iptables: Flushing firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]
iptables: Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: filter          [  OK  ]
iptables: Unloading modules:                               [  OK  ]
$ sudo nano /etc/sysconfig/iptables
$ sudo service iptables start
```

When nano opens, cut the `REJECT` line and uncut it below the two new rules, then writeout and quit.

Also, you'll need to ssh from localhost just once before you can do it from the outside.